# How to notify users in network

Tags: python, notify

I have a task to monitor disk usage and notify a few users when it runs out of space. I wrote python script that checks disk usage. Unfortunately I can't use email notification from the script because company policy does not allow it.
My question: Are there any other options that would allow me to notify selected users in my network about particular event i.e. full disk space? I mean some kind of message that will pop-up on the screen or etc.
Please keep in mind that I practically don't have any administrative privileges in the network.
Thanks

Comment: If you don't have administrative privileges on your network, why do you care about monitoring other people's disk space?

Comment: Your company assigned you the task of notifying users but also said that you can't do it via email.  Why not ask them what form of notification they had in mind?

Comment: Well ... We are just a small team of a few people who care about the disk space on a particular server. Company will not monitor disk usage on that server. It is our responsibility. Company also has strong security policy and won't grant admin privileges for regular user and also API access to mail server. That's why I am thinking of alternative option of notification my team. Not sure if it is possible and that's why I am asking for advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... I figured out that in my organization Microsoft Exchange will not allow email started from script except those originated from server.
I handled to start email from server and now I'm all set.
Thanks for suggestions.
Ticket could be closed.